# How to hide titlebar of the QDialog window?

Tags: qt, dialog, hide, titlebar

I show a dialog in my qt application on menu action click window is appearing perfectly but I want to hide its title bar as it is just a sub-window inside main window.

I tried :

```
this->setWindowFlags(Qt::Window |Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
```

In dialog constructor:

```
ui->setupUi(this);
this->setWindowState (Qt::WindowActive);
setWindowModality(Qt::ApplicationModal);
setAttribute (Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
this->setWindowFlags(Qt::Window |Qt::FramelessWindowHint) ; //
```

This does remove the title bar but it also hides the main window, which is bad for my application.

How can I hide dialog title bar without disturbing the base main window of the application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QDialog remove title bar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30181630/608639).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 QDialog *dialog(new QDialog /* this should be your dialog class youve created obviously*/));
 dialog->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::Dialog);
 dialog->show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the CustomizeWindowHint.

As you can see from the [source code here](https://github.com/Vitallium/qt5/blob/master/qtbase/src/widgets/kernel/qwidget.cpp#L1032) (line 1035) for QWidget, it decides what to do depending upon that flag. So I suggest trying this: -

```
setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint);
```

Comment: ur suggestion is working in same way as   this->setWindowFlags(Qt::Window |Qt::FramelessWindowHint)  , it does hides the titlebar of the window but also dislocates the mainwindow of the application.

Comment: thanx ur answer is fine but it is not right for my application because i want to hide the title bar of the "dialog" and not a window. your answer works fine with mainwindow widget